# R make install failing, missing documents

Tags: r, compilation, gnu-make, document

I'm attempting to compile and install R 3.6.1 from the tar.gz on Ubuntu 18.04.  All appears to go fine during configure and make, and then when attempting to install I get this

```
installing doc ...
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat 'NEWS': No such file or directory
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat 'NEWS.pdf': No such file or directory
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat 'NEWS.rds': No such file or directory
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat 'NEWS': No such file or directory
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat 'NEWS.pdf': No such file or directory
Makefile:121: recipe for target 'install-sources2' failed
make[1]: *** [install-sources2] Error 1
```

I have no idea what could have caused this, have compiled numerous versions before with no problem.

My configure statement looks like this:

```
./configure --enable-R-shlib --with-blas=-lopenblas --enable-memory-profiling
```

Any idea what is going wrong?  This is a new machine, could I be missing something basic like a document or pdf handler?
Thanks,
J

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but you might consider installing using the instructions [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html).

Comment: Thanks Axeman.  I think those instructions explain how to download and install the already-compiled binary versions.  I used them for years but now I need compiled versions that connect to mpi software.  I don't think the compiled versions do this automatically.

Comment: This problem re-emerged in R 3.6.3 when it was not able to do this: `make[1]: Entering directory '/home/fifis/Downloads/R-3.6.3/doc'`, `installing doc ...`, `/usr/bin/install: cannot stat 'NEWS.pdf': No such file or directory`. After I created a zero-byte NEWS.pdf via `touch doc/NEWS.pdf`, the problem went away.

Comment: @AndreïKostyrka I encourage you to make your comment to an answer as I had the same issue and I don't want to install 1GB of latex as I never need it.

Answer (score 3):

After a suggestion in the comments, I am posting my solution that circumvents the problem via the let-them-eat-cake approach—create the necessary zero-byte files:

```
cd doc
touch NEWS NEWS.pdf NEWS.rds
```

If something else (from the non-essential bunch) is missing, you can easily `touch` the missing things to make the compiler gobble the dummies.

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem!  New machine trying to get it up running quickly and had not yet installed latex.  Installed Latex and all went fine.

Apparently this is picked during the configure stage but is not a fatal error.  Perhaps it should b?